# CMake : Could NOT find Qt5FontDatabaseSupport

Tags: linux, cmake, qt5

I got the following error after running `cmake` for [this](https://github.com/KDE/kwin) :

```
Could NOT find Qt5FontDatabaseSupport (missing:
Qt5FontDatabaseSupport_LIBRARY Qt5FontDatabaseSupport_INCLUDE_DIR) (found
version "5.12.8")
```

I cannot find any package with that name in my linux repository.
That is one of the dependencies for the Qt `QPA` plugin , as stated in the `CMakeLists.txt` comments.

I use `Kubuntu` 20.04 with `cmake` 3.16 and `Qt`5.12.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `qtbase5-dev` is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you don't have the build dependencies installed. Qt5FontDatabaseSupport is part of the `gui` Qt module, for which the headers and devel files are installed with the `qtbase5-dev` package.
Kwin has many more build dependencies than qtbase, so the best if you install all of them with:

```
sudo apt build-dep kwin
```

at once, or with

```
sudo apt build-dep kwin-wayland
```

if you want to hack it under wayland.

Comment: I had "qtbase5-dev" completely installed.But the problem was somewhere else.I didn't know "build-dep" command.That's the solution .Thank you very much :)